# SQLite: Extract Terms and Doc Count of terms from full text index

Tags: sqlite, indexing, full-text-search

I have a table that is a full text index.

How do I extract a list of the terms that the full text indexer used and the number of documents it was in

example

```
friend   2
fiend    4
found    45
fast     3
```

etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create a ftsaux table after the index table was made:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE MYTABLE_terms USING fts4aux(MYTABLE);
```